# Why are the Low Quality deletion reasons not available outside of the review queue?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

When I'm browsing questions and I come across an answer that fits one of the *Recommend Deletion* reasons from the Low Quality review queue, I'm not able to flag the answer with one of those reasons.

For example, when a user posts an answer along the lines of "thank you @user, your answer helped me", in the review queue you can recommend deletion with *This is a “thank you” comment* and it will automatically post a comment saying *“Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.”*

I guess this is intentionally not available outside of the review queue, but why is that?

---

Just noticed, some answers have a *it is very low quality* flag reason available while other's don't. What controls the availability of this flag reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those posts are Not an Answer.  Flag them accordingly.  If you have 20k rep, you may also be able to vote to delete the post.

You can only flag posts with a score of 0 or less as Very Low Quality.